# Build queries based on the properties of edges, NOT the existence of edges in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this type of Cypher statement checks for the *existence* of a relationship:

```
start n=node(*)
match (n)-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]-()
return distinct n
```

To quickly reiterate, if `[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]` is simply present, then we will get a match and a result.

But what happens if your graph is set up in such a manner, that **all** your nodes have `[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]`. And the distinguishing factor between these relationships is contained *in* the relationship?

In other words, say I have an edge that is packed with properties. In fact, the edges in my graph have more properties than the nodes they connect do.

I'm finding it difficult to query such a graph, since the Cypher syntax only allows me to check if a relationship exists. I want to build queries based on the properties of the edges! Is this allowed in Cypher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to make queries using relationship properties. You can do it in the same way as for nodes:

```
match (n)-[r:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]-()
where r.someProperty = someValue
return distinct n
```

or

```
match (n)-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP { someProperty: someValue }]-()
return distinct n
```